# Argument Out Of Range Exception Occured

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
    string Calc = Console.ReadLine();
    char[] operands = { '+', '-', '/', '*' };
    int index = Calc.IndexOfAny(operands);
    if (index != -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Calc.Substring(index));
        var thing = Calc.Substring(index);
        foreach (var x in operands)
        {
            if(Calc.Substring(index).Contains(x))<------------
            {
                Calc = Calc.Split(x)[0];
                Console.WriteLine(Calc + "new");
                Console.WriteLine("Working");
                thing = thing.Replace(Convert.ToString(x), "");
                Calc = Calc.Replace(" ", "");
                Console.WriteLine("{0} first value",Calc);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} operand value", x);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} second value", thing);
                index = Convert.ToInt32(index);
                switch(x)
                {
                    case '+':
                        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(Calc) + Convert.ToInt32(thing));
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(Calc) - Convert.ToInt32(thing));
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(Calc) / Convert.ToInt32(thing));
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(Calc) * Convert.ToInt32(thing));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Please excuse my sloppy code. I was just wondering why I'm getting an Argument Out Of Range error? Honestly I have no idea what I'm meant to do about it. It just happens. I've arrowed  where the error occurs.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code line by line with your IDE's debugging tools to see where execution differs from what you believe it should be? Also, you should say which line of your code is throwing the exception.

Comment: Run it in the debugger - you are overwriting the `Calc` variable but are not recomputing `index`.

Answer (score 0):

After you have done the calculation and reduced `Calc` to the part to the left of the operator you still keep looping through the operators. When you check for the next operator there is no operator in the string any more, i.e. `index` points to a position outside of the string.

Instead of looping through the operators to find the operator that is the operator, just get the operator from the string:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("");
    string Calc = Console.ReadLine();
    char[] operands = { '+', '-', '/', '*' };
    int index = Calc.IndexOfAny(operands);
    if (index != -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Calc.Substring(index));
        string thing = Calc.Substring(index + 1);
        char x = Calc[index];

        Calc = Calc.Substring(0, index);
        Calc = Calc.Replace(" ", "");
        Console.WriteLine("{0} first value",Calc);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} operand value", x);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} second value", thing);
        switch(x)
        {
            case '+':
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(Calc) + Convert.ToInt32(thing));
                break;
            case '-':
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(Calc) - Convert.ToInt32(thing));
                break;
            case '/':
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(Calc) / Convert.ToInt32(thing));
                break;
            case '*':
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(Calc) * Convert.ToInt32(thing));
                break;
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine(); }
```